# Type 'keyof T' does not satisfy the constraint

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I get this error despite the validation working. All I need is a function that generates another function using an object to filter arguments of a fixed type

```
Type 'keyof T' does not satisfy the constraint '"a" | "b" | "c"'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"a" | "b" | "c"'.
    Type 'keyof T' is not assignable to type '"c"'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"c"'
```

```
type GM = {
    a: number;
    b: string;
    c: string
}

type VMeth<T, C > = (old: T, n: C) => any;

const getVF = <T extends { [key in keyof Partial<GM>]: 1 }>(part: T):  VMeth<GM, Pick<GM, keyof T>> => {
    return function(){ } as any
}

const fd = getVF({ a: 1 });

fd({ a: 1, b: "", c: "s"}, { a: 1 });
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=38#code/C4TwDgpgBA4gslAvFA3gKCpqBDAXFAOwFcBbAIwgCcBuDLM-AZ2EoEsCBzWrKAYyZbsOaAL5o0oSFABqcCMAAWAHgAqAGigBhKAD4kUABQB7ADYATfOsL5NASiR7sBELTS8jBZlA7zpAMX1VKAgAD2AIAjNGVCgAbQBrCBAodihEkCMAMygABWxKYFZsEyV4HQBdfABGKBEdAzB84EtbfBk5RVK4DRzWXniujXSsqBUdPUQ9dB5KeSJKAihMogJeQo8DWxRanGinEFFxd09gJbN9H2B-A228KBqRW1dMsxucao0GKAAib41+H6Mb4iDS3aq1J5AA)

Comment: You haven't said enough about what you are trying to do, so it is rather hard to give you an answer (you also didn't ask an explicit question). The answer will depend on whether what you're doing is type-safe (in which case it's about getting the type declarations right) or not (in which case it's about getting the rest of the code right), so you need to edit the question to include all the relevant details. Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: You're getting that error for a good reason: `getVF({ a: 1, oops: 1 });` is allowed because `{a: 1, oops: 1}` is assignable to `{a?: 1, b?: 1, c?: 1}`. Perhaps you want [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBz4VN) behavior instead (see the `Fix` section)?  If so let me know and I'll write up an answer; if not, please edit the question to elaborate on what you're trying to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constraint

```
T extends { [key in keyof Partial<GM>]: 1 }
```

means that `T` must be assignable to `{a?:1, b?:1, c?:1}`.  This includes types you are trying to support, like `{a: 1}`.  But it also includes types you are apparently *not* trying to support.  Object types in TypeScript are *extendable* or *open* (as opposed to *exact* or *closed*).  You are allowed to extend an object type by adding properties to it.  So the type `{a?: 1, b?:1, c?:1, oops: string}` is also supported:

```
const oopsie = getVF({ a: 1, oops: "oops" }) // no error!
// const oopsie: VMeth<GM, Pick<GM, "a" | "oops">>
```

Because `T` may in fact have more keys than `GM`, the compiler rightfully complains that

```
// Type 'keyof T' does not satisfy the constraint 'keyof GM'.
```

---

If you really want to limit the keys of `part` to those of `GM` (or at least only pay attention to those keys, since object types are open no matter what you do), you can make your function generic in those keys `K` instead:

```
const getVF = <K extends keyof GM>(part: Record<K, 1>):
    VMeth<GM, Pick<GM, K>> => {
    return function () { } as any
}
```

Now `K` must be some subset of the union of `"a" | "b" | "c"` and cannot be `"oops"` or anything else.  And so `Pick<GM, K>` will always work.  Your desired use case still functions the same:

```
fd({ a: 1, b: "", c: "s" }, { a: 1 });
// const fd: (old: GM, n: Pick<GM, "a">) => any
```

And now we get compiler warnings if we obviously add an unexpected property:

```
getVF({ a: 1, oops: "oops" }); // error, excess property!
```

You can still manage to get such an excess property in there if you are sneaky:

```
const existingObj = {a: 1, oops: "oops"} as const;
const aliased: {a: 1} = existingObj;
const okay = getVF(aliased); // no error
// const okay: VMeth<GM, Pick<GM, "a">>
```

But at least the value that comes out is still `Pick<GM, "a">` and not something invalid like `Pick<GM, "a" | "oops">`.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=27&ssc=38&pln=26&pc=36#code/C4TwDgpgBA4gslAvFA3gKCpqBDAXFAOwFcBbAIwgCcBuDLM-AZ2EoEsCBzWrKAYyZbsOaAL5o0oSFABqcCMAAWAHgAqAGigBhAHxIoACgD2AGwAm+dYXyaAlEl3YCIWmgLYSERmGy9oABUpDMmMIElQ6TF5DAmYoDnlpADE9VSgIAA9gCAJTRlQoAG0AawgQKHYoEpBDADMoP2xKYFZsYyV4bQBdfABGKBFtfW8mixtcCJ4ZOUV2uA0-Vl4i2Y0q2qgVbV1EXXRJrEp5IkoCKBqiAl5m6IM7FH6cPMcQCbEJqJjgM9M9eOAk-T3PBQPoiGzcLAAekhfGisRq5gMJkR8A0BHwCyWKygACJsDjtHYdjgnOIeAjAThehoGLicRp+LjGDj+hogb1+uCyVgPrFDIYwIxWNBkH8AeyQRp+YL8DjpczOVBoYRDGlKIFKABCCbK3lfeXC-CyeTKVH1RbLM14lkAH1x8oJ2nEYjcHi8PmgiVY6XCPD1cQSyWQSgA0mlMtlcpVSusOkNGsB8AAlCBRSimUMaHqE8b7TDGmZmzGWuZQENbey+vOHYDHU7nS7XU76O4PbBPUk8N5+uFfBG-QOU4GgrkTCkSno02X0viyhUiNlUkGciGYXW9774IxmfBm9HmrFW-GEyvPbmYMWJIfUqDy2UOldKmFUDUaDK+Rh5MCBSBNEDa94NwyVhmCEAB5MgACs9BQYcpQFRh7wQnEREeWFPlXdDYlaFpGAgRFYN6VDkGA0DOAgyDMP9QwimwMpRUHHD23w8EnxVNUNR1GFqNokAjWmU1S2LbFrS2UQgA)

Comment: I really appreciate you explaining this to me in such rich detail! I'm glad that now I have a simpler method for doing runtime type/validation checks